# Asp.Net Identity - Updating Claims After Login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I am using asp.net identity (WebApi 2, MVC 5, not .net core) to add claims to my user's identity when she logs in from our singe page application.  This looks like this (I have stripped out the checks for invalid names, locked accounts, etc)

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<CompWalkUserManager>();
    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
    var check = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, context.Password);
    if (!check)
    {
        await userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user.Id);
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", invalidUser);
        return;
    }

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
        OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    //These claims are key/value pairs stored in the local database
    var claims = GetClaimsForUser(user);
    cookiesIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
    oAuthIdentity.AddClaims(claims);


    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
    context.Validated(ticket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
}
```

At this point, everything is working as expected.  I can check the user's claims via an `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` as methods on my api are called.

However, it is possible that an administrator might change the values of the claims while the user is logged in (our tokens are good for 14 days).   As an example we have a claim named `Locations` with a value of `EditAndDelete`.   The admin might change this value to `NoAccess` in the database,  but the authentication will not know about about this.

I can see that at run-time I can add or remove claims from my `identity`, but these changes do not persist past the current request.   Is there a way to update the auth ticket in the cookies on the fly?  I would like to be able to update my `Identity` with the new value without having the user have to log out.

Comment: One option for this kind of thing is to run middleware at the beginning of the request which adjusts the claims for that request.  This won't persist in the cookies but it would solve your underlying problem.

Comment: @nurdyguy i have considered that (and am leaning in that direction), but once I go down that path what is identity bringing to the table other than authorization?

Comment: I've used that method before with success.  The biggest drawback is the extra db hits but you really can't avoid that if there are changes "on the fly".  Have you tried a sign-out then sign-in on same request?  I haven't tried that before, not sure if it works for refreshing the token.

Comment: The OAuth way of doing things like that is that your access tokes should be short lived (e.g. 15 min or 1hour at most). Then the client has to use its refresh token to get a new access token. The new access token will contain the new cliams. Furthermore, IIRC, there is a way to revoke access tokens which invalidates them immediately.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go the Identity way of doing that, you need to hit the db on every login. You set the `SecurityStamp` validation interval to 0:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        { 
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });
```

When the permissions are changed for a user, you update their securitystamp:

```
UserManager.UpdateSecurityStamp(userId);
```