# Claims added to ClaimsIdentity getting lost in ASP.NET Core Identity System

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my **ASP.NET Core Identity** I have noticed that my claim that I add are **getting lost**.

First I have a Create claim view having a form to create a claim. The **claim is added to the currently logged in user**.

The code of the Action method is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
public IActionResult Create_Post(string claimType, string claimValue, string claimIssuer)
{
    ClaimsIdentity identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    Claim claim = new Claim(claimType, claimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String, claimIssuer);
    identity.AddClaim(claim);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The clain is added on this line - `identity.AddClaim(claim);`.

Now the last line is redirecting to Index action method whose code is:

```
public ViewResult Index() => View(User?.Claims);
```

The Index View which is showing all the claim for the user is:

```
@model IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Issuer</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var claim in Model.OrderBy(x => x.Type))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@claim.Subject.Name</td>
            <td>@claim.Issuer</td>
            <td>@claim.Type</td>
            <td>@claim.Value</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Example: I added a claim, see the below image
[image]

But the Index View did not fetched the claim, see the below image:
[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save the claims to `User?.Claims`, you need to call `_signInManager.Context.SignInAsync` with updated `ClaimsIdentity`.

Follow steps below:

- Extension for signin with new `ClaimsIdentity`

  ```
  public class CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<TIdentityUser> where TIdentityUser : IdentityUser
  {
  private readonly SignInManager<TIdentityUser> _signInManager;

  public CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper(SignInManager<TIdentityUser> signInManager)
  {
      _signInManager = signInManager;
  }

  public async Task SignInUserAsync(ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
  {
      await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
  }

  }
  ```
- Register `CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<TIdentityUser>`

  ```
  services.AddTransient<CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<IdentityUser>>();
  ```
- Update User Claims

  ```
  public class IdentityController : Controller
  {
  private readonly CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<IdentityUser> _signInHelper;
  private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
  public IdentityController(CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<IdentityUser> signInHelper
      , UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
  {
      _signInHelper = signInHelper;
      _userManager = userManager;
  }
  public ViewResult Index() => View(User?.Claims);


  [HttpGet]
  [ActionName("Create")]
  public IActionResult Create_Post()
  {
      return View();
  }

  [HttpPost]
  [ActionName("Create")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create_Post(string claimType, string claimValue, string claimIssuer)
  {
      ClaimsIdentity identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
      Claim claim = new Claim(claimType, claimValue, ClaimValueTypes.String, claimIssuer);
      identity.AddClaim(claim);
      await _signInHelper.SignInUserAsync(identity);

      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
   }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Claims added to a authenticated user will not persisted through others requests. Claims must be added before login.

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153541/add-claims-on-successful-login-and-retrieve-it-elsewhere-in-the-application) to see how to add claims to the user.

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617699/asp-net-identity-updating-claims-after-login) for an example on how to change user claims after login.