# .Net Core 2.2 - WsFederation - User Claim not updating

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, adfs3.0

I am working on a .Net Core 2.2 Razor Page application that authenticates with ADFS 3.0 using WsFederation.  This is working and the user is authenticated and I can retrieve the claims of the user.

I can also retrieve a Refresh Bearer Token through the Authorization Code flow with ADFS 3.0.  This short lived refresh token would be used to access an internal WebAPI.  I am trying to add a new User Claim that would be this Refresh Bearer Token. For some reason after I update the claims list (I see it added using QuickWatch), and access that list of claims in another Page the new claim is no longer available, the list resets back to what it was after initial authentication.

I am re-using the same code I used when doing this in .Net MVC5.  Now I was reading that it some cases it may require the user to re-login.  However I did not have to re-login when I did this in .Net MVC5.  I am a bit confused, because I am not sure if this is .Net Core issue or have I been doing it wrong this whole time with the MVC 5 project.

I investigated accessing the User via HttpContextAccessor,  injecting it updating the claims list, but it did not yield any new results.

```
public class RefreshTokenModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;


    public RefreshTokenModel(IConfiguration config, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _config = config;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {

        //var curIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var curIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        bool needToken = false;

        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(_config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:ADFSAuthority"), false);

        try
        {

            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(_config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:oAuthClient"), _config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:oAuthClientSecret"));

            AuthenticationResult _authResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:ADFSResourceIdentifier"), _config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:oAuthClient"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authResult.AccessToken) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_authResult.AccessTokenType))
            {
                //curIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
                 curIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity;
                var bearerToken = curIdentity.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "BearerToken").SingleOrDefault();

                if (bearerToken != null)
                {
                    curIdentity.TryRemoveClaim(bearerToken);
                }

                curIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("BearerToken", _authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader()));

            }
            needToken = false;

        }
        catch (AdalException adalEx)
        {
            needToken = true;
        }

        if (needToken)
        {
            var authorizationURL = await authenticationContext.GetAuthorizationRequestUrlAsync(_config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:ADFSResourceIdentifier"), _config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:oAuthClient"), new Uri(_config.GetValue<string>("ADFSIdentitySettings:ADFSRedirectUri")), new UserIdentifier(User.Identity.Name, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId), "");

            return new RedirectResult(authorizationURL.AbsoluteUri);
        }
        return new PageResult();




    }
}
```

My Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {

            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        }).AddWsFederation(options =>
        {
            options.Wtrealm = "http://applicationname/razor";
            options.MetadataAddress = "urltofederationmetadata.xml";

        })
         .AddCookie();

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {

               // options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Areas/Pages/Settings"); //set authorization on just a single folder
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/"); //- set authorization on all folders and pages
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }
```

Comment: If you want to save the claims to `User.Claims`, you need to call _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync with updated ClaimsIdentity.Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52657546/11398810)

Comment: Was this always the case? Or did this become a thing when .Net Core came out?